# Replicate Curve Constraint on mesh objects that are following multiple paths using animation nodes

Tags: animation, modifiers, animation-nodes, constraints, loop

I am working in Animation Nodes.

I have created a randomly curved "wiggly" Path across a surface. I have made a long thin Mesh object that follows the Path using a Curve Modifier, this attached to an Empty with a Follow Path Constraint. It works beautifully. Now I need to replicate it.

I have replicated the Path using an Object Instancer. I have replicated the Empty, one to each Path, using another Object Instancer and a Loop that takes the vectors from the Path instances.

Now I want to replicate the Follow Path Constraint to all of the Empties, each with a random delay on the start frame. Then I want to replicate the Mesh objects so each one attaches to an Empty and has the Curve Modifier binding it to its Path.

Imagine you wanted to make a bunch of millipedes each walking along a different stick, starting at different times.

Can anyone help with the Node/Loop structures to achieve this? Thanks in advance!